# store additional data in QAction menu item - python

Tags: python, pyside

I've got a dynamic qmenu which is generated via a for-loop. I've broken this down to its most basic properties possible. What I'm wondering, is it possible for me to create a custom QMenuItem so i can store an actual object inside each menu item? Currently it only supports just string which is used as the name.

How can I store additional data/information in a Menu Item?

I want to set the display text, like normal and then additionally in the for loop, add a class object, or data of some sort, to each item as well. I placed pseudo code in the for-loop but it's commented out..

I thought i was close by creating a custom QAction item and inheriting from QAction but that didn't appear to work when trying to use this...

```
class ActionObject( QtGui.QAction ):
    def __init__( self, text="", parent=None ):
        super( ActionObject, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.data = None
```

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name="", age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

# Main Widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        # formatting
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # context menu
        self.main_menu = QtGui.QMenu()

        self.sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu("Great")
        self.main_menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu)


        names = ["Joe","Kevin","Amy","Doug","Jenny"]

        # sub-menu
        for x in xrange(len(names)):
            name = str(x) + " - " + names[x]
            action = self.sub_menu.addAction( name )
            # action.data = Person()
            action.triggered.connect(self.menu_action)

        # widgets        
        self.factionsList = QtGui.QListWidget()

        # signal
        self.factionsList.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.factionsList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_factions)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.factionsList, 1, 0)
        self.show()

    def menu_action(self):
        print "testing"


    def on_context_menu_factions(self, pos):
        self.main_menu.exec_( QtGui.QCursor.pos() )


# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWidget()
    res = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use setData to set data and below you have a working example and I changed your code bit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name="", age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

# Main Widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        # formatting
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # context menu
        self.main_menu = QtGui.QMenu()

        self.sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu("Great")
        self.main_menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu)


        names = ["Joe","Kevin","Amy","Doug","Jenny"]

        # sub-menu
        for index, name in enumerate(names):
            fancyName = "%s - %s" % (index, name)
            action = self.sub_menu.addAction( fancyName )
            action.setData(Person(name=name))
            action.triggered.connect(partial(self.menu_action, action))

        # widgets        
        self.factionsList = QtGui.QListWidget()

        # signal
        self.factionsList.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.factionsList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_factions)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.factionsList, 1, 0)
        self.show()

    def menu_action(self, item):
        itmData = item.data()
        print itmData.getName()


    def on_context_menu_factions(self, pos):
        self.main_menu.exec_( QtGui.QCursor.pos() )


# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWidget()
    res = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(res)
```

Comment: whats the need for partial?

Answer (score 1):

Of course as Achayan answered, you can use `QAction`'s `setData()` to set additional data, and `data()` to get stored data.

Above, however, will solve your problem, let's look on extending QAction. The `QWidget`, `QMenu` is based on, implements `addAction` that allows to pass `QAction` object.

```
class ActionObject( QtGui.QAction ):
    def __init__( self, text="", parent=None ):
        super( ActionObject, self ).__init__(text, parent )
        self.data = None

class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

        # ...[cut]...

        def initUI(self):

        # ...[cut]...

            # sub-menu
            for x in xrange(len(names)):
                name = str(x) + " - " + names[x]
                action = ActionObject(name, self.sub_menu)
                action.data = Person()
                action.triggered.connect(self.menu_action)
                self.sub_menu.addAction(action)
```

The parent has been set explicitly, since it is `QWidget`'s implementation, not `QMenu`.

This is how PyQt/Pyside allows to use custom object, almost everywhere - without using monkey patching.

Comment: thank you @kalmAcetA this was helpful to see how it would be done thanks